# UI (component) Dispatcher (property) under .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm going through the book "Programming in C#" by Rob Miles (MS Exam ref 70-483) and there's an example using tasks and wpf. The problem is it seems to be in .NET core, while I'm trying to learn .NET Framework (my boss still wants me to use .NET Framework.)

The original code is

```
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        long noOfValues = long.Parse(NumberOfValuesTextBox.Text);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            double result = computeAverages(noOfValues);

            ResultTextBlock.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "Result: " + result.ToString();
            });
        });
    }
```

But in .NET Framework the UI components don't seem to have the property `Dispatcher`. I've been Googling for hours, but haven't found a good solution. Best I've come up with is

```
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long noOfValues = long.Parse(NumberOfValuesTextBox.Text);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            double result = computeAverages(noOfValues);

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "Result: " + result.ToString();
            }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        });
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work... The `ResultTextBlock` label is never updated. What's going wrong?

(p.s. The author of the book acknowledges that the code example is not a good programming practice. It's just for demonstration purposes.)

edit: proof

> error CS1061: 'Label' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no accessible extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You don't need `Dispatcher` for asynchronous methods in either .NET Framework or .NET Core when `async/await` are available. `Dispatcher` came from .NET Framework anyway, and existed before Tasks and `async/await` were added. It was used to update the UI from other threads back when the only alternative was to use `BeginInvoke`

Comment: In the code you posted, you should use `var result =await Task.Run(()=>computeAverages(noOfValues));` and update the UI *after* the task completes. If you want to report progress (whatever that may mean) you can use the [IProgress<T> interface and Progresss<T> class](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). This allows you to report progress from classes and methods far away from the UI

Comment: @Clemens then my visual studio is broken. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: @canton7 i'm doing that in my own example.

Comment: `... are you missing ... an assembly reference?` - probably WindowsBase.dll. And why do you call a Label Result**TextBlock**? Label does not have a Text property, but Content.

Comment: @Clemens I used the WPF form designer to try to replicate the application. There's no `TextBlock` in the Toolbox.... I think there's the problem. The form designer doesn't seem to offer all UI components.

Comment: @Clemens And I see my (`System.Windows.Forms.`)`Label` having a `Text` property....

Comment: System.Windows.Forms is not WPF. It is [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/). WPF controls are in System.Windows.Controls.

Comment: @JHBonarius a broken VS doesn't affect what API libraries and properties are available. Don't post a screenshot, that would be useless. Post the XAML instead - the snippet that defines `ResultTextBox`. I suspect you used a WinForms TextBox instead of a WPF TextBlock

Comment: @Clemens aarg. there are multiple UI frameworks? I thought the 'F' in WPF stood for 'Form'. OK, I'll delete the question and start another tutorial. edit: OK, I cannot delete the question... new SO policy it seems

Comment: @JHBonarius Windows Forms, WPF, UWP (XAML-ish for Windows Store), WinUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in .NET Framework the UI components don't seem to have the property Dispatcher.

That is not true. Just make sure you are using a WPF TextBlock  instead of a Windows Forms Label. Also call the Dispatcher's `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method.

Besides that, the example is broken. The Click handler should be `async` and await the Task.Run call:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    long noOfValues = long.Parse(NumberOfValuesTextBox.Text);

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        double result = computeAverages(noOfValues);

        ResultTextBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            ResultTextBlock.Text = "Result: " + result.ToString();
        });
    });
}
```

Even better would be not to use the Dispatcher at all:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    long noOfValues = long.Parse(NumberOfValuesTextBox.Text);

    double result = await Task.Run(() => computeAverages(noOfValues));

    ResultTextBlock.Text = "Result: " + result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes The author gives your second code after this example. I state that the author acknowledges that it is not a good coding practice.

Comment: @JHBonarius `it's broken` is far worse than `not a good coding practice`. Exam preparation books are a terrible way to learn a language or framework

Comment: And my `ResultTextBlock`, nor any of the other UI components have the property `Dispatcher`. I'm not making this up.

Comment: @JHBonarius in this case, there's just no reason to use Dispatcher, not since 2012. The `Dispatcher` example exists only because the API is still in the exams

Comment: @JHBonarius If it does not have the Dispatcher property, it is not a WPF TextBlock. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock?view=netframework-4.8#properties

Comment: it's a `Label`. I couldn't find the `TextBlock` object in the Toolbox bar. But I understood all UI components should have the `Dispatcher` property?

Comment: @JHBonarius Sure, and see my comment on the question.

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. `TextBlock` is not in `System.Windows.Forms`. It's in `System.Windows.Control`.

Comment: @JHBonarius looks like you used a WinForms control in a WPF application

Comment: I'll just accept this answer. My mistake was that I was using a Windows Form application instead of a WPF application. Didn't know they were different things.